# Is there a way to resolve this template circular dependency

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a general approach to solve this type of circular dependencies in template or is it impossible to make work?

```
#include <tuple>

template<class... T>
struct A {
    std::tuple<T...> t;
};

template<class type_of_A>
struct D1 {
    type_of_A* p;
};
template<class type_of_A>
struct D2 {
    type_of_A* p;
};

using A_type = A<D1<???>, D2<???>>;  // <------

int main() { }
```

Comment: smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). what do you want to achieve? (btw I already found it difficult to understand what is the problem, but I have no idea what this would be good for)

Comment: Replace the `???` with a type, like `int` or `double`, and it will work.  It isn't a circular dependency.

Comment: @Eljay The naming strongly hints that `???` is supposed to be (equivalent to) `A_type` itself.

Comment: Then it may be a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) situation.

Comment: The type is `A<D1<A<something>>, ...>`. Now if something is again D your design is broken. If it is something else then I don't see the problem.

Comment: @biowep that's not broken, that's just a recursive type. Looks like some kind of N-ary tree to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, insert a named indirection into the mix to break the infinite recursion:

```
template<class... T>
struct A {
    std::tuple<T...> t;
};

template<class type_of_A>
struct D1 {
    typename type_of_A::type* p; // Indirection
};

template<class type_of_A>
struct D2 {
    typename type_of_A::type* p; // Indirection
};

// Type factory while we're at it
template <template <class> class... Ds>
struct MakeA {
    using type = A<Ds<MakeA>...>; // Hey, that's me!
};

using A_type = typename MakeA<D1, D2>::type;
```

The behaviour of `MakeA`s injected-class-name is a bonus, but we could spell it out as `MakeA<Ds...>`.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd50c3a87ae7e0f6)

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks. One more question: is it possible to make D1 and D2 non-template?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov yes, that's simpler in fact. You just have to declare the `p`'s to be `A<D1, D2>*`.